# Where does AXI storage the contending packages?

Tags: xilinx, axi4

Assume the interconnect is busy at the moment, and there is a master that wants to read/write something to a slave. So, is this request stored temporarily at the interface or at the interconnect itself? I assume AXI store these signals coming from channels in some FIFOs. However, I do not know where are these FIFOs.

If it is a design-specific problem, how Xilinx implements it?

Comment: It's implementation specific. FIFOs can be anywhere. In master itself or in interconnect slave/master interface, or in slave itself ...

Comment: "AXI" is just the bus protocol (or rather, a whole family of protocols), it doesn't "store" anything anywhere; your things attached via AXI can or cannot choose to do that internally.

Answer (score 0):

AXI is just a protocol. It sets how signals must behave, it doesn't mandates bus topology or how contentions are handled.

About Xilinx, their AXI crossbar IP has optional register buffering option to relaxe timings (but can add latency) and also optional FIFOs.
Anyway, a properly written AXI device should respect the protocol in every case, with and without FIFOs, FIFOs are just for optimising performance, concurrency,...

Answer (score 0):

Usually what happens is the interconnect does not accept the new request, and the master has to hold on to the request until the interconnect is ready to accept it.  But it is possible that add FIFOs here and there to store requests until the interconnect (or other components) are ready to accept them.

But this is entirely implementation-dependent as AXI is just a protocol that describes the type and format of all of the supported operations, but doesn't mandate any particular implementation.